# How to check text displayed in a validation message using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

[image]

I need to check a validation message as in the image is displayed on clicking save button without entering value in a specific field.

How to check this alert is displayed and can I verify the text displayed in this message?

HTML code:

```
<form id="h_team" class="ajax-form" action="/dashboard/healthcareteams/add/"    name="myteam" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="nOL6zUe7ASnde3OsRDLkiCQO8gEdKH2w" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
<fieldset>
<legend class="sr-only">Contact Type</legend>
<input id="id_contact_type" type="hidden" value="1" name="contact_type">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-11" style="margin-top:4px">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="id_name" class="form-control input-custom" type="text" title="" required="required" placeholder="Insurance Name" name="name">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There a xpath for that particular message, you can find that xpath and check, if that xpath webElement text is empty or not.

Comment: @Saritha I am not able to take xpath of message because when I click on inspect element using firebug the message gets closed. I found this messageusually gets disappeared after a few seconds

Comment: Can you post your URL?? or HTML code?

Comment: @SarithaG I have added the html code

Comment: This code is before displaying that msg. When you entered wrong value into that input then that will show that message..right?? So once enter wrong data into it,then it will show ** span** or some other tag with the validation message, then you can post your html code here.

Comment: @saritha the code I think was working was actually wrong, the test found pass even if I enter a wrong value as below verifyElementPresent id=id_name /*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')].Also no speciala tags are actually generated on code while displaying validation message. I think it is an HTML 5 validation

Answer (score 0):

You can store text present in the alert into a variable as follows:

```
String msg_in_alert=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

Then you can use `assert` to compare:

```
 Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(
      By.cssSelector("selector_of_error_element")
     ).getText().compareTo(msg_in_alert), true);
```

Where `true` specifies that the text should match.

If text does not match, it will result in step failure.